# Cannot drop a role that is granted to connect database

Tags: sql, postgresql, dependencies, privileges, sql-revoke

I am using PostgreSQL 10.4 and I found a strange behavior.

If we create an role and grant it to `CONNECT` the database:

```
CREATE ROLE dummy;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE test TO dummy;
```

Then we cannot drop this role, even if it owns no object at all, this command:

```
DROP ROLE dummy;
```

Raises:

```
ERROR: role "dummy" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
SQL state: 2BP01
Detail: privileges for database test
```

[Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html) is a bit misleading:

> Class 2B — Dependent Privilege Descriptors Still Exist
>
> 2B000 dependent_privilege_descriptors_still_exist
>
> 2BP01 dependent_objects_still_exist

It says **dependent objects still exist**, but it seems there are no objects dependent to this specific role, it owns nothing on the database.

Anyway, if we revoke the `CONNECT` privilege, then role can be dropped:

```
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE test FROM dummy;
DROP ROLE dummy;
```

I just checked the behavior also exists on PostgreSQL 9.5. I feel it a bit strange and I cannot understand why this specific privilege makes dropping role fails.

**Additional observations**

This is really blocking, because we can neither reassign this object:

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY dummy TO postgres;
```

Nor drop the object:

```
DROP OWNED BY dummy;
```

Both raise related errors:

> ERROR: permission denied to reassign objects
> SQL state: 42501

> ERROR: permission denied to drop objects
> SQL state: 42501

As @RaymondNijland pointed out, this must be because the `CONNECT` privileges is viewed as a role dependent object. The following query:

```
WITH
R AS (SELECT * FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = 'dummy')
SELECT
    D.*
FROM
    R, pg_shdepend AS D
WHERE
    refobjid = R.oid;
```

Returns a single row when `CONNECT` is granted:

```
"dbid";"classid";"objid";"objsubid";"refclassid";"refobjid";"deptype"
0;1262;27961;0;1260;27966;"a"
```

And no row at all when the privilege is revoked. This at least explain why we cannot reassign the object.

About the Dependency Type, the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-shdepend.html) states:

> `SHARED_DEPENDENCY_ACL` (a)
>
> The referenced object (which must be a role) is mentioned in the
> ACL (access control list, i.e., privileges list) of the dependent
> object. (`A SHARED_DEPENDENCY_ACL` entry is not made for the owner of
> the object, since the owner will have a `SHARED_DEPENDENCY_OWNER` entry
> anyway.)

But I have not enough insight to understand it clearly.

My question are:

- Do Postgres always require to revoke privileges before dropping a role?
- If not, why this specific privilege behaves like this?

Comment: ""It says dependent objects still exist, but there are no objects dependent to this specific role, it owns nothing on the database."  Well the connect privilege looks to be a dependent object on the role dummy  like the errors say `Detail: privileges for database test` ...The system catalog `pg_shdepend` ( https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-shdepend.html ) should have this dependency relationship

Comment: @RaymondNijland Your remark does make sense. I have updated my post according to the information you have highlighted and modified my question. Would you mind to check it again? Thank you anyway

Comment: "Do Postgres always require to revoke privileges before dropping a role?" https://doxygen.postgresql.org/user_8h.html#a94c380b5f5c9a22404bc1407d4ccc7a4 DropRole functions source code of PostgreSQL there is a function checkSharedDependencies() in there.. So yes this is required to drop the dependent objects like privileges

Answer (score 11):

There are some very unintuitive permission requirements when using `REASSIGN`.

I have found that when a superuser account is not available (as in the case of RDS or Cloud SQL) I have to grant the target role to my current role in order to reassign or drop owned objects from the target role.  For instance, if my active user is `postsgres`, and I'm trying to remove `user_a`:

```
> DROP OWNED BY user_a
ERROR:  permission denied to drop objects
> GRANT user_a TO postgres;
GRANT ROLE
> DROP OWNED BY user_a;
DROP OWNED
```

Now, it becomes a little trickier if `user_a` happens to be a member of `postgres`, especially if it happens to inherit that membership through some other role, let's call it `schema_admin`...

```
> DROP OWNED BY user_a
ERROR:  permission denied to drop objects
> GRANT user_a TO postgres;
ERROR:  role "user_a" is a member of role "postgres"

-- Alright, let's try to revoke it...
> REVOKE postgres FROM user_a;
REVOKE ROLE
> GRANT user_a TO postgres;
ERROR:  role "user_a" is a member of role "postgres"

-- It's still a member through the inherited grant - trying to revoke again doesn't work:
> REVOKE postgres FROM user_a;
WARNING:  role "user_a" is not a member of role "postgres"
REVOKE ROLE

-- So you have to identify the role it's inheriting from, and revoke that:
> REVOKE schema_admin FROM user_a;
REVOKE ROLE
> GRANT user_a TO postgres;
GRANT ROLE

-- Now just to be safe, I'll reassign owned objects before actually dropping everything:
> REASSIGN OWNED BY user_a TO postgres;
REASSIGN OWNED
> DROP OWNED BY user_a;
DROP OWNED
> DROP ROLE user_a;
DROP ROLE;
```

Voila!

Note: There is another widely-referenced and effective answer here: https://sysadmintips.com/services/databases/postgresql-error-permission-denied-to-reassign-objects/ which works great, as long as you are able to create and log in as a new temporary user.  However, in some contexts, that is a problem in itself (and then you also have the extra cleanup to handle of removing that temporary role when you're done), so I tried to avoid that here.

Comment: Seriously, this was driving me crazy, running an RDS and thought that my main user is a super user. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to run [REASSIGN OWNED](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-reassign-owned.html) and [DROP OWNED](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-drop-owned.html). The 1st way is with a superuser and the 2nd way is with a normal user.

### <The 1st way>:

For example, first, log in to `apple` database with any superuser e.g., `postgres`. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57975093/create-a-superuser-in-postgres/77260939#77260939) explains how to create a superuser. and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757431/postgres-upgrade-a-user-to-be-a-superuser/77274571#77274571) explains how to make a user a superuser:

```
psql -U postgres apple
```

Finally, you can run `REASSIGN OWNED` and `DROP OWNED` as shown below:

```sql
REASSIGN OWNED BY david TO peter
```

Or:

```sql
REASSIGN OWNED BY peter TO david
```

Or:

```sql
DROP OWNED BY david;
```

Or:

```sql
DROP OWNED BY peter;
```

### <The 2nd way>:

For example, first, log in to any database e.g., `postgres` database with any superuser e.g., `postgres` as shown below:

```
psql -U postgres
```

Then, create the user `john` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE ROLE john WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'banana';
```

Then, grant the users `david` and `peter` to the user `john`, exit as shown below:

```sql
GRANT david TO john;
GRANT peter TO john;
\q
```

Then, log in to `apple` database with the user `john` as shown below:

```
psql -U john apple
```

Finally, you can run `REASSIGN OWNED` and `DROP OWNED` as shown below:

```sql
REASSIGN OWNED BY david TO peter
```

Or:

```sql
REASSIGN OWNED BY peter TO david
```

Or:

```sql
DROP OWNED BY david;
```

Or:

```sql
DROP OWNED BY peter;
```

Comment: For me, the crucial detail in this answer (that I didn't find elsewhere) was granting the 'child' role to the 'parent' role so that parent role could later run DROP OWNED BY